# Showing that an implicit function is continuous

Tags: implicit-function

I want to show that the following implicit function is continuous:
$$2x = \ln(|x+iy-1|)-\ln(|x+iy+1|)$$
I plottet the function with mathematica and it seems to be continuous, but i would like to show it in an analytic way.

Is there a good way to show continuity of implicit functions?

Comment: Probably a silly question, but i is the square root of -1, correct?

Comment: yes, thats correct